# Printing numbers 1-100, except when divisible by 5 or 12

Tags: java, acm-java-libraries

The question is

> Write a Java program that prints numbers from 1 to 100. If the number is divisible by 5, instead of printing the number, your program should print how many fives are in this number, if the number is divisible by 12 it should print how many twelves are in this number.

Here's my current attempt:

```
import acm.program.*;

public class FiveTwelve extends ConsoleProgram {
    public void run() {
        int a = (1);
        int b = (5);
        int c = (12);
        for (a = 1; a <= 100; a++) {
            println(a);
            if ((a % 5) == 0) {
                println(a/b);
            } else if ((a % 12) == 0) {
                println(a / c);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that my code is also printing the divisible number instead of just the outcome. Example output:

```
1
2
3
4
5
1
6
7
8
9
10
2
11
12
1
```

This goes on. I want to remove numbers that are divisible by 5 and 12. Instead, I need to show the result or num/5 && num/12.

UPDATE!!!

```
import acm.program.*;
public class FiveTwelve Extends ConsoleProgram{
public void run() {
    for (int a = 1; a <= 100; a++) {
        if (a % 5 == 0 && a % 12 == 0) {
            println(a / 5);
            println(a / 12);
        } else if (a % 5 == 0) {
            println(a / 5);
        } else if (a % 12 == 0) {
            println(a / 12);

        } else {
            println(a);
        }
    }
}
}
```

guess we all missed something.

Comment: Big hint: `println(a);` is not restricted by any condition so it always execute. Try to explain where should it be executed and where not. Then try to code it that way.

Comment: Note: also think about the time that 'a' is divisible by both 5 and 12. This would be missed because you use an "else if"

Comment: Not to get too mathematical but [this guide](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Modular_arithmetic/Introduction#Multiplication) will help you understand exactly what @Anoml is saying. If you're up for the challenge, you may explore and even try proving their [properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic#Properties)

Answer (score 3):

Instead of solving for the specific case, let's write an extensible solution. First, what variables are there in the question that could change? I'd say they are:

1. The starting number `1`
2. The last number `100`
3. The divisors `5` and `12`

Additionally, as @Anoml pointed out, the problem wording suggests that if your number is divisible by multiple divisors, we should print out the number of times it is divisible for *every* applicable divisor. And, as you noted in your question, we only want to print the number itself when it is not divisible by *any* divisors.

So, our solution becomes:

```
import acm.program.*;

public class FiveTwelve extends ConsoleProgram {
    private final int FIRST = 1;
    private final int LAST = 100;
    private final int[] DIVISORS = { 5, 12 };

    public void run() {
        boolean hasDivisor;

        for (int i = FIRST; i <= LAST; i++) {
            hasDivisor = false;

            for (int divisor : DIVISORS) {
                if (i % divisor == 0) {
                    println(i / divisor);
                    hasDivisor = true;
                }
            }

            if (!hasDivisor) {
                println(i);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This way, we can change our starting number, last number, or which divisors we support, and the program will still pass.

Answer (score 1):

This is what you intended to do, `println(a)` in all other cases.

```
for (int a = 1; a <= 100; a++) {
    if (a % 5 == 0) {
        println(a / 5);
    } else if (a % 12 == 0) {
        println(a / 12);
    } else {
        println(a);
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't forget the case of a=60, it is divisible by 5 and 12.

Comment: @Anoml spoil sport, but right. OP: always ask yourself why they build in two conditions.

Comment: @JoopEggen this is a traditional fizzbuzz question, you would print both conditions.

Comment: Thanks for actually realising my intentions. This was my purpose by starting but as others mentioned there are examples like number 60 which is divisible by both 5&12.The example of yours should be my choice for an edit because Im currently a beginner and dont have much knowledge over previous answers.